# How to suppress MaxPermSize warning?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

How can I suppress MaxPermSize warning, when compiling Scala project in IDEA/SBT project? Or where I can turn this option off? I can't find any settings for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In IntelliJ IDEA, open Preferences (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> on Mac OS X) and type in `scala` in the search field on the top left-hand side.

Or just go to `Other Settings` -> `Scala`:

[image: scala]

Go to `Settings` -> `SBT`:

[image: sbt]